# Input loop with FIFO problems

Tags: linux, bash, shell, redirect, fifo

I'm having some trouble using FIFOs for stdin.

I have a script like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby
while true do
    data = gets
    puts "Got: #{data}"
end
```

Then I run it like:

```
$ ./script < input.fifo &
$ echo testdata > input.fifo
```

It will print something like:

```
Got: testdata
Got:
Got:
Got:
Got:
Got:
etc.
```

My suspicion is that something is wrong with the FIFO. That something is not getting cleared out after it is sent to the script.

I tried the same thing with a C program with a similar input loop using a scanf("%d" ...) and it acted like this:

```
$ echo 1 > input.fifo
Got: 1
Got: 1
Got: 1
Got: 1
etc.
```

So it would seem that the last thing in the FIFO gets stuck there. In the ruby example, it is a null line, because gets captures the \n. In the second it is the 1 itself.

Can anyone offer any insight?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The situation is simple, after:
'echo 1 > input.fifo', the file 'input.fifo' was opened, "1" was written to it,
and it is closed.

The problem is that it is closed. When fifo closed from writing side, this is equal "end of file" for reading side. So if you check return code from "scanf" in your C example it will be equal to EOF constant.

And after "end of file" when you read all data from fifo, and try read something,
the "reading" code will alaways return immediately and report "end of file".

Comment: Hmm, maybe I'm using the wrong tool then. Basically I want something that allows me to direct user input to a script, and for the script to wait when there is no more input. When something else is added to the input file, I want to execute the next line. Any idea how I might do this?